# "ToDictonary" throws exception when used on Mocked object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have this abstract class

```
public abstract class DisposableList<T> : List<T>, IDisposable
{
    protected DisposableList();

    public virtual void Dispose();
}
```

and this Interface

```
public interface IGroup : IDisposable
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

I need to test this method

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(IConnection connection)
    {
        var groups = connection.GetGroups();
        var grps = groups.ToDictionary(x => x?.Name); //Here gets System.NullReference exception
    }
}
```

In testing, so far what I did is:

```
var group1 = new Mock<IGroup>();
group1.SetupGet(c => c.Name).Returns("abc");

var groups = new Mock<DisposableList<IGroup>>();
groups.Object.Add(group1.Object);

Mock<IConnection> connection.Setup(c => c.GetGroups()).Returns(() => groups.Object);

new MyClass().MyMethod(connection);
```

but `var grps = groups.ToDictionary(x => x?.Name);` gets `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

`Name` is not null and `groups` is not null. Something happens inside.

how can I fix this?

Comment: You are better off creating a derived class and using that instead of trying to mock it with Moq.

Comment: I got no chance. I cannot change the code and need to test it.

Comment: You are not changing production code. you are creatig a stub for the purposes of the test. that is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set null value as dictionary key like this; (It is possible to be null)

```
groups.ToDictionary(x => x?.Name);
```

Eliminate the items which is null or has null `Name` value.

```
groups.Where(x => x != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name)).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: This seems like I need to change the Production code. But definitely works!